# File-or-glob argument in dockerfile while using TestCafe runner

Tags: testing, automation, dockerfile, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm new into `TestCafe` and I'm trying to write a dockerfile using testcafe image.
In testcafe documentation, they say I have to pass the `File-or-glob ...` argument, which specifies the files or directories (separated by a space) from which to run the tests.
The problem is that I use a generic runner, **which gets a fixture name**, and then execute its test, **on demand, when ever the user asks for a screenshot.**
That is why I'm confused what to put in the docker run command, I thought it should be the runner file.
Runner:

```
const takeScreenShot = async(fixtureName:string, testName:string) =>{
 const testCafe= await createTestCafe('localhost');
 try{
     const runner = testCafe.createRunner();
     await runner
     .src(`src/testcafe-automations/${fixtureName}.ts`)
     .filter(testRequested=>testRequested===testName)
     .browsers('chromiuim:headless')
     .screenshots({fullPage:true, path: screenshotsPath})
     .run()
   }
}
```

docker command:
`$ docker run -v ${PWD}:/tests -it --entrypoint node testcafe/testcafe 'chromium:headless --no-sandbox' '/tests/src/testcafe-automations/utils/runner-file.ts'`

This is a node project, and I'm not sure if I even need this in my docker, I was also wondering of using in `circleCI` image. The only thing I need is taking screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you use `docker run` to start TestCafe docker image, it just passes specified arguments to the `testcafe` command in the container. If you are using a `Runner` object, use `node` to run the script that uses it.
Since you've already overwritten the default [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime) with the `node` executable, you can pass the name of the runner script and the fixture name as arguments:

```
docker run -v ${PWD}:/tests -it --entrypoint node testcafe/testcafe '/tests/src/testcafe-automations/utils/runner.js' 'fixtureName'
```

In the `runner.js`, you should call your function with command-line arguments passed to Node.js (read them by using [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv))

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try, but is it possible to use ```circleci/node:14-browsers``` image  with browser for example,  and just use ``` .browsers('chrome:headless')```? will it work on my container?

Comment: It should work wherever there are installed Node.js, the TestCafe package, and a browser. TestCafe provides a preconfigured Docker image in order to make preparation of testing environment easier (preinstalled browsers, Node.js, the TestCafe package, a script to configure services like Xvfb and Dbus so TestCafe can run browsers in non-headless mode, etc). So, I recommend this way of running tests in Docker.